# Adding a general method to datarowitems (Extension)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add a method to all objecttypes, similar to `.toString()`. I will use it primary for datrowitems (and these get autocasted through the sqltype).

I want to call it like `myDatarow("myField").myMethod()`. Is it possible to add a method in general without extending each possible objecttype for itself? Is there a general type which all other types are inheriting from?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In a hunch, I somehow don't like what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ John Oh ok. I will avoid this in future.    @ G. Stoynev what's the matter with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to add this method to the datarowobject itself because mydatarow("Field") can be of any type and doesn't inherit datarow.

One of the option to achieve what you need is to extend DataRow like normal, but pass the column name as the parameter. Eg (in VB though):

```
<Extension> Sub myMethod(dr As DataRow, columnName As String)
    If dr.Item(columnName) Is DBNull.Value Then
        ' your code
    ElseIf TypeOf dr.Item(columnName) Is String Then
        ' your code
    Else
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Therefore, instead of your intended call like `myDatarow("myField").myMethod()`, you can call it like so:

```
myDatarow.myMethod("myField")
```

Comment: Seems to be the better way round. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All classes are inheriting from the `Object` class. So you may try adding an extension method to `Object` class.

But think twice and decide you really want to do this. Why do you need to add an extension method to every possibly type ?

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't work. Extending Object doesn't work for types (a method for object won't be a method for integer). I'm trying easy to handle dbnullexceptions this way for example (like toString does) but for other types like integer (throug adding .toInteger() as method).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use extension methods. An extension method is something like a normal method but is defined in another class.

In your case it will look something like this:

```
public static class MyMethods
{
     public static MyResult MyMethod(this DataRow row)
     {
          //code goes here, you can access only the public members of the row class 
     }
}
```

Comment: i guess he wants to add the extension method to all types, not only to datarow

Comment: Shyju is right. I don't want to add this method to the datarowobject itself because mydatarow("Field") can be of any type and doesn't inherit datarow.